# How do I update IcedTea?

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, java, gtk

I've only been using Linux for about a month.  I'm running Mint 13.  I'm trying to use www.goproblems.com but it tells me that my IcedTea is out of date.  I hoped there was a package but I can't find it.  I tried building it from source but that failed.

I read that it requires GTK+, but when I checked that out, the site said GTK+ is dependent on 5 other packages that I might have to install, from source.

My question is: **If there is an IcedTea package, where is it?**

(Also, can someone recommend an online resource that teaches me how to do this well?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux Mint is Ubuntu-based, you can install packages from the Ubuntu repositories. You may have to change your `/etc/apt/sources.list` if you cannot find the package in the Software Manager.

IcedTea is in the Universe repository, which should be enabled by default. You can also find the relevant packages by [searching](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=Icedtea&searchon=names&suite=precise&section=all) the Ubuntu repos.